# TypedQuery<T>.getSingleResult returns object of type Class instead of type T

Tags: java, openejb, apache-tomee

I have spent literally two days on the problem and I'm no closer to solving it. I hope that one of the experts out there can help.

Here's the problem. I'm Using TomEE 1.6.0.2 (OpenEJB 4.6.0.2) and trying to do a simple TypedQyery that returns a single result and I am getting the strangest return value. It's not the bean object that I expect--it's a java.lang.Class!!

Here's the code fragment:

```
public static Account getAccount(String type, String key, EntityManager em) {

    try {
        TypedQuery<Account> query = em.createNamedQuery("Account.getByTypeAndKey", Account.class)
            .setParameter("type", type)
            .setParameter("key", key)
            .setMaxResults(1);

        Account account = query.getSingleResult();  // This statement throws an exception
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());         // "java.lang.Class cannot be cast to beans.Account"
    }

    try {
        TypedQuery<Account> query = em.createNamedQuery("Account.getByTypeAndKey", Account.class)
                .setParameter("type", type)
                .setParameter("key", key)
                .setMaxResults(1);

        Object object = query.getSingleResult();    // This works

        System.out.printf("object is '%s'\n", object.toString());
        // "object is 'class beans.Account'"

        Account account = new Account();
        System.out.printf("account is '%s'\n", account.toString());
        // "account is 'Account{id=0, type='null, etc... }'"

        return account;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());         // Never gets here
    }
}
```

Here's a fragment of the Account class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Account")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Account.getByTypeAndKey", query = "SELECT Account FROM Account rec WHERE rec.key = :key AND rec.type = :type"),
})
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String type;

    // The usual stuff ...
}
```

And here is persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="unipagosPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

        <jta-data-source>PAY_AccountDSJta</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>PAY_AccountDSNonJta</non-jta-data-source>

        <class>beans.Account</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true, MaxActive=10, MaxIdle=5, MinIdle=2, MaxWait=60000"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I'm sure this is something really easy, but I'm not able figure this one out. What's going on?!

TIA for your help...

Comment: I think you have to cast explicity `Account account = (Account)query.getSingleResult()`

Comment: I've tried it either way and, with or without the explicit cast, the code blows up with the same error ("java.lang.Class cannot be cast to beans.Account")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is wrong. It should be

```
SELECT rec FROM Account rec WHERE rec.key = :key AND rec.type = :type
        ^-- use the alias here, and not the class name
```

Comment: OMG...that was *it*!! Now that I see the solution, the problem makes perfect sense to me. Using "Account" means the class (totally wrong) but using "rec" means the instance of that class. Thank you so much!